# How to select the timeseries that have changed over a given time period?

Tags: prometheus, promql

The changes function returns the number of changes for a timeline over a period of time. I would like to use this value to filter out time series that have not changed during the last 24hrs.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you don't need values for doing what you're asking "to filter out time series that have not changed during the last 24hrs". Try to find all series which didn't for last 24h change via the following query:

```
changes(metric_selector[24h]) == 0
```